# Set URL using powershell list add

Tags: powershell, folder, url

When creating a new library using PowerShell the URL of the library is not the same its name. What parameter do I need to specify to set the target URL?

```
$WebUrl = "http://sharepoint/sites/teams/teama"
$title = "Images"
$description = "Images"
$spweb    = Get-SPWeb -Identity $WebUrl
$listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary  
$spweb.Lists.Add("$title","$description",$listTemplate)
```

This produces:
<kbd>http://sharepoint/sites/teams/teama/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Images1/</kbd>
which should be:
<kbd>http://sharepoint/sites/teams/teama/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Images/</kbd>

Comment: It seems you have already library named Images

Comment: Thanks Atish. You are correct, there is a folder named 'images' created for a new subsite. 

This library does not appear in the site contents view - _layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx - so I was creating a folder with a name which already existed.

Instead of throwing an error SharePoint was 'helpfully' creating a new library with the same name and different url.

Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can mark it as the answer to this for future reference by anyone else who experiences this.

Comment: Welcome!. Added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when you have already a library/folder named Images and now you are trying to create a new Library/folder by the same name. Sometimes it can not be found in site content view so try to find it by PowerShell or SharePoint Designer.